# How merge image with python pillow into center of an another image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

[image]I have two images. I want to merge one image into the other but it has to be perfectly in the middle?

```
im1 = Image.open('image1.png')
im2 = Image.open('image2.png')
back_im = im1.copy()

#location of image

back_im.paste(im2,(370, 330))
back_im.save('newimg.png', quality=95)
```

Comment: Okay, so what do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? I assume you thought of something like: draw the "bottom" image, then figure out a position where the "top" image should be drawn, then draw the "top" image at that position. Right? What part of this do you need help with? Or else, if that doesn't describe the task you have in mind, then **what do you mean by "merge"?**

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Please see edits.

Comment: I know how to merge but I am trying to merge it so that it is perfectly in the middle.

Comment: Okay, so where the code says `back_im.paste(im2,(370, 330))`, how did you decide on the `(370, 330)` numbers? Do they give you the result you want? If not, how far off is the position, or else what else is wrong? Can you think of a mathematical rule, in terms of the dimensions of each image, that tells you what the coordinate should be?

Comment: No the numbers are no good. I am trying to figure out how to center it.

Comment: Well, what's wrong with the numbers? What rule did you use to decide them, and why should that rule work?

Comment: Those numbers are random. It just to show you how I am merging them.

Comment: Merge might not even be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

You have to calculate the center point of the larger image, then the top left position of the inner image is offset it 1/2 of it's height and width. For example

```
# Get dimensions of each image
width1, height1 = im1.size
width2, height2 = im2.size

# Find center pixel of outer image
center_x, center_y = (width1/2), (height1/2)

# Offset inner image to align its center
im2_x = center_x - (width2/2)
im2_y = center_y - (height2/2)

# Paste inner image over outer image
back_im = im1.copy()
back_im.paste(im2,(im2_x, im2_y))
```